# Never prompt me again with the words "Buffer modified"

Tags: kill-buffer, confirmation

I would like to know how I can never again be prompted when I invoke the command

`kill-this-buffer`

with the words

`Buffer <name> modified; kill anyway?`

I would thus like to kill the buffer immediately without saving any changes made to the buffer and without having to say yes or no or even y or n. I understand changes will be lost.

Comment: I cannot in good conscience recommend that you bypass that question: it has saved and will continue to save the hides of many Emacs users (from noobs to gurus, I imagine): it has certainly saved mine on multiple occasions.

Comment: It depends on the tasks one is performing from within Emacs. When sorting through large numbers of files, it is cumbersome. In other contexts it could be a necessary. In my opinion Emacs requires too many confirmations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reviewing the implementation of `kill-buffer`, I see that the `kill-buffer-query-functions` hook gets called before the "Buffer modified" prompt is presented to the user.  You might try resetting the `buffer-modified-p` flag using `(not-modified)` with something like the following:

```
(add-hook 'kill-buffer-query-functions
          (lambda () (not-modified) t))
```